# Ошибки при запуске сервера spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

**Код:**

```or-tag-here
package backend.dao;

import backend.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryImpl extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select u from User u where u.name = :name")
    User findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

---

```or-tag-here
package backend.service;

import backend.model.User;

import java.util.List;


public interface UserService {

    User addUser(User user);
    void delete(long id);
    User getByName(String name);
    User editUser(User user);
    List<User> getAll();
}
```

---

```or-tag-here
package backend.service.implementation;

import backend.dao.UserRepositoryImpl;
import backend.model.User;
import backend.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepositoryImpl userRepository;

    @Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        userRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getByName(String name) {
        return userRepository.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public User editUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

---

**applicationContext.xml**

```or-tag-here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="backend.*"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

</beans>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```or-tag-here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <mvc:annotation-driven />

       <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

       <context:component-scan base-package="backend"/>

       <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
              <property name="basenames">
                     <list>
                            <value>classpath:validation</value>
                     </list>
              </property>
       </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
              <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
       </bean>
</beans>
```

**appconfig-data.xml**

```or-tag-here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
   </bean>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="backend.model"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
    </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
           <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
       </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

       <jpa:repositories base-package="backend"/>

</beans>
```

---

На сколько я понял, ошибки две:

```or-tag-here
Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [appconfig-data.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

и

```or-tag-here
 WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext#1005 Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 01 09:51:46 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

**Стэк:**

```or-tag-here
Connected to server
[2017-04-01 09:51:43,842] Artifact dealback:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
01-Apr-2017 09:51:46.090 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
09:51:46.365 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.c.ContextLoader#304 Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
09:51:46.455 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext#582 Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 01 09:51:46 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
09:51:46.539 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader#317 Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
09:51:46.613 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader#317 Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
09:51:46.850 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.XmlBeanDefinitionReader#317 Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]
09:51:46.885 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] ERROR o.s.w.c.ContextLoader#350 Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [appconfig-data.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:259) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4754) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5216) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.12]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.12]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:243) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:61) ~[spring-dao-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:61) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
01-Apr-2017 09:51:46.898 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    ... 67 common frames omitted
09:51:46.902 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext#987 Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 01 09:51:46 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
01-Apr-2017 09:51:46.899 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
09:51:46.916 [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext#1005 Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Apr 01 09:51:46 YEKT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) [spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4801) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5438) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.12]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.12]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
[2017-04-01 09:51:46,941] Artifact dealback:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
01-Apr-2017 09:51:53.399 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\manager
01-Apr-2017 09:51:53.452 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\webapps\manager has finished in 53 ms
C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\bin\catalina.bat stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\kosty\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\tomcat\Unnamed_dealback_4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\kosty\IntellijProjects\Plugins\apache-tomcat-8.5.12\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

Comment: <import resource="dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>
Уберите из applicationContext.xml

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Если appconfig-data.xml и Applicationcontext.xml находятся в одной папке и import не срабатывает, то попробуйте так: <import resource="classpath*:appconfig-data.xml " />

Comment: Не может найти файл.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь версии модулей спринга.

Если не находится какой-то метод в классах спринга на этапе инициализации контекста, значит у какого-то модуля не та версия.